# Keycloak returns Unauthorized 401

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, oauth, postman, keycloak

I'm running bitnami's Keycloak image on my local.
what I want to do is; use Keycloak REST APIs.
but no matter how hard I try, I'm getting 401.

I have done what's written in the doc. so this is a screenshot of the client. `access type` is `confidential`, and a service account is `enabled`. this is `testapi` client that I created;
[image]

here you can see the service account roles;
[image]
to view and manage users, I assigned `manage-users` and `view-user` roles.

firstly, to get the `access_token` , I'm using `client_id` and `client_credential`.
as you can see from here;
[image]
I have no problem getting the access token.

but when I try to get the user list or create a new user, I always get 401.
here you can see that I used the SAME access_token that I got from the http://localhost:8092/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token

[image]

it doesn't make sense. I started to think about smashing the computer.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

##### For anyone having the exact same issue and ending up on this page, here is the solution:

1. Keep all your keycloak settings at default, no matter you are using `bitnami/keycloak`, or `keycloak/keycloak`, there is absolutely nothing you have to change in admin console.
2. Call this endpoint with the `GET` method: ⬇️

   ```bash
   curl -X GET http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration
   ```

   Make sure the **issuer endpoint** is correct.
3. Request the token via this command: ⬇️

   ```bash
   access_token=`curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=admin-cli" -d "username=user" -d "password=bitnami" -d "grant_type=password" -d "scope=openid" "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq -r .access_token`
   ```

   Make sure you didn't forget the `scope=openid`.
4. Validate this token by calling `userinfo` within **60 seconds**: ⬇️

   ```bash
   curl -H "Authorization: bearer ${access_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "scope=openid" "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
   ```

   Make sure you didn't forget the `scope=openid` too.